# Ruby JSON parse from AWS Lambda 785: unexpected token

Tags: json, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've got an Jira webhook connected to the Lambda AWS. In a response from webhook I've received an JSON file but I don't know how to parse it to get such a value like `user_email` or `user_id`.

JSON file from the response is huge, here is a sample:

```
"{\"resource\"=>\"/event\", \"path\"=>\"/event\", \"httpMethod\"=>\"POST\", \"headers\"=>{\"Accept\"=>\"*/*\", \"Accept-Encoding\"=>\"gzip,deflate\", \"CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto\"=>\"https\", \"CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer\"=>\"true\", \"CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer\"=>\"false\", \"CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer\"=>\"false\", \"CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer\"=>\"false\", \"CloudFront-Viewer-Country\"=>\"IE\", \"Content-Type\"=>\"application/json; charset=UTF-8\", \"Host\"=>\"ongnx6d1vk.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com\", \"User-Agent\"=>\"Atlassian Webhook HTTP Client\", \"Via\"=>\"1.1 1234.1234.net (CloudFront)\", \"X-Amz-Cf-Id\"=>\"fdgsfds==\", \"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\"=>\"Root=1-fsdafaaf\", \"X-Atlassian-Webhook-Identifier\"=>\"12345\", \"X-B3-Sampled\"=>\"1\", \"X-B3-SpanId\"=>\"13421a324\", \"X-B3-TraceId\"=>\"1fdasfjkl\", \"X-Forwarded-For\"=>\"32423, 342141\", \"X-Forwarded-Port\"=>\"443\"}"
```

Because of the Lambda limitations in debugging I've downloaded JSON to a file so I've tried to use parse method, with no results:

```
  class JiraParser
    def initialize
      @event = JSON.parse(File.read("../devops-bot/lambda_response.json"))
    end

    def call
      puts parse_reporter_email
    end

    private

    attr_reader :event

    def parse_reporter_email
      event.dig('issue', 'reporter', 'emailAddress')
    end
  end
```

With this code I've got an error

> parse_reporter_email': undefined method `dig' for string

I was trying to change `parse` method to:

```
response = JSON.parse(File.read("../devops-ticket-bot/lambda_response.json"))
@event = JSON.parse(response["body"])
```

But it gave me an error:

> 785: unexpected token at 'body' (JSON::ParserError)

Comment: can you try double parsing? `response = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(File.read("../devops-ticket-bot/lambda_response.json")))
@event = JSON.parse(response["body"])` Also it seems the json is not correct. Looks like you did `some_hash.to_s`

Comment: JSON passes based on https://jsonlint.com/. After double parsing I've got the same error as in my previous solution: `785: unexpected token at`

Answer (score 1):

`"{\"resource\"=>\"/event\" ..."` is not a valid `JSON`. Valid `JSON` would be `"{\"resource\":\"/event\" ...}` (note a colon not a hashrocket.)

That probably was caused by you dumping your test data as `hash.inspect` instead of `JSON.dump(hash)`.

Comment: Ok but I just copy/paste what I've got from the lambda error logs, it begins with `"errorMessage": "{\"resource\"=>\"/event\", ... ` so how this may not be a valid json?

Comment: I have no idea about lambda error logs, but it is **indeed not a valid json**. Maybe they spit out a dump of ruby object, I dunno. Try `JSON.parse('{"foo"=>42}') ` if you do not believe.

Comment: Some APIs give you a choice of formats (e.g. via `format=json`, `format=xml` etc parameter). Sometimes those choices include `ruby`, which can be inserted into Ruby code directly, or executed using `eval`, instead of parsing with `JSON.parse`. And sometimes, if there is no default, the API endpoint will inspect your User Agent header, and guess. Just like @AlekseiMatiushkin, I don't know lambda, but it is conceivable it saw a request made by Ruby, and sent the response in Ruby format.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your first code block is what is literally present in the file.

*data.json*

```json
"data"
```

The above is valid JSON, no matter the contents of the string. In your case the string contains a Ruby data structure.

When you parse the file the output would be a string:

```
require "json"

data = JSON.parse(File.read("data.json"))
#=> "data"
```

When you then try to call `dig` on the result it raises an exception because a string doesn't respond to the `dig` method. However it does respond to `[]`.

```
data["ta"]
#=> "ta"
```

When you pass the result of `response["body"]` into `JSON.parse` you simply providing the string `"body"` (or `nil` if `"body"` can't be found in the string). Since `body` isn't valid JSON an exception is raised.

JSON can be either a string, number, object, array, `true`, `false` or `null`. The literal `body` doesn't fit any of the before mentioned.

---

A way to retrieve the data as intended is to evaluate the Ruby code:

```
ruby_code = JSON.parse(File.read("../devops-bot/lambda_response.json"))
response = eval(ruby_code)
response.dig('issue', 'reporter', 'emailAddress')
#=> ...
```

Which should give you back the structure.

**Note that you have to trust the file, since it can execute anything it wants.**

---

The better question is: Why is the data saved in such a weird way to the file? I'd have a look at the code that is writing the files and make sure you output actual JSON or YAML to a file, since that's safe for reading without using `eval`.